# knex query keep asking for sqlite module install

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sqlite, knex.js

I'm trying to create a query using knex, by using postgres as database. However when I run the code it keep asking

> Error: Cannot find module 'sqlite3'

Even though I have added `pg` to my knexfile.

**Query**

```
var data = {
    id: leagueId,
    slug: leagueSlug,
    createdAt: new Date()
};
var query = knex('league').insert(data).toString();
query += ' on duplicate key update ' + knex.raw('createdAt= ?, id = ?',[new Date(), id]);

knex.raw(query);
```

**knexfile**

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      user: 'test',
      database: 'test'
    }
  },
  production: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL
  }
};
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var parse = require('body-parser');
var knex = require('knex');
var Log = require('log');
var router = express.Router();
var log = new Log('info');



    /* Retrieve and save leagues*/
    router.get('/api/league', function(req, res, next) {

  /* exclude slugs */
   var excludedSlugs = [ 'eu-cs', 'na-cs', 'iwc', 'all-star'];

   request({
   method: 'GET',
   uri: 'http://test',
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'dataType': 'json'}
 }, function (error, response, body){
   if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){

     var bodyJSON = JSON.parse(body);
     var leagueObjects = bodyJSON["leagues"];

     for(var objIndex in leagueObjects){
       if (excludedSlugs.indexOf(leagueObjects[objIndex]["slug"]) > -1) {
         /* excluded slugs - do nothing */

        } else {
          var leagueId = leagueObjects[objIndex]["id"];
          var leagueSlug = leagueObjects[objIndex]["slug"];

          var data = {
              id: leagueId,
              slug: leagueSlug,
              name: "lol",
              createdAt: new Date()
          };
          var query = knex('league').insert(data).toString();
          query += ' on duplicate key update ' + 'createdAt= ?, id = ?',[new Date(), leagueId];

          knex.raw(query);


        }
     }


     res.json(leagueObjects);
   } else {
     log.error(error);
   }
 })
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Where You read **knexfile**?

Comment: @Peter Pik please profive your project layout. also the parte where you instantiate the query builder (the var knex = // ... part). Also please take a look a this sample project layout, it shows how to use the same knexfile.js used by migrations: https://github.com/sombriks/blogpost-upload-express-knex/blob/master/index.js

Comment: added more layout now. here i'm trying to retrieve data from an rest api and add into my postgres db using knex

Comment: Hey @PeterPik - did you find a solution? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: yes @Joseph check answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. i was not reading the knexfile correctly what i did was to create a seperate db.js file with:

```
var config      = require('../knexfile.js');
var env         = 'development';
var knex        = require('knex')(config[env]);

module.exports = knex;

knex.migrate.latest([config]);
```

then i used

```
var db  = require('./db');
```

then i use knex like

```
db.knex()
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a knex versioning issue, I used **postgesql** instead of **pg** in knexfile.js client